# How to enable the "results" attribute in <input type="search">?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm trying to make use of the `results` attribute of HTML5 `<input type="search">` tags on Chrome, which should make for a "recent searches" funcionality.

I cannot manage to make Chrome show a list of recent searches, not even on [this demo page](http://wufoo.com/html5/types/5-search.html). When you input a few searches, and then click the arrow next to the magnifying glass, a list of recent searches should appear. Somehow, nothing happens when I click that arrow.

I'm using Chrome 16 on Windows, if that matters (the screenshots on the demo page seem to be taken on a Mac, where it apparently does work).

What am I missing? Is there possibly a some setting in Chrome that I may have turned off accidentally?

Comment: It does say "Chrome 6-13" in the compatibility table...

Comment: @BoltClock: Good catch! Though, I can't get it to work on Chromium 10 either. It behaves exactly the same - nothing happens when clicking the arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like chrome doesn't fully support that attribute.

How about autocomplete...
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.search.html#input.search.attrs.autocomplete

There is more info regarding chrome support for the results attribute in the chromium bug/issue list.
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=77779
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17

Comment: The results attribute is not actually part of the HTML5 specification, http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.search.html

Answer (score 0):

Add a "name" (or "id") attribute and it should work in Chrome. You'll need a `<form>` element around it with a valid `action="..."` attribute as well.

```
<input type='search' results='5' name='something'>
```